# Analytical probability of acceptance for MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, analytical

When we do MCMC algorithm we search for a tradeoff between probability of acceptance for each step and typical size of steps undertaken during each iteration of the sampling algorithm.

Are there any simple but meaningful examples, when we can derive probability of acceptance analytical as e.g. a function of the variance of the proposal distribution?

I tried to compose an example on the base on univariate normal, but even in this case the formulas seems to be too complicated and technical to be used for demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the famous paper that proposed the 0.234 rule for the acceptance rate of the Metropolis algorithm:

> [Weak convergence and optimal scaling of random walk Metropolis algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoap/1034625254)

They obtain some closed-form expressions for the optimality criterion used in the paper, and derive the popular 0.234 rule.